# Convergence of $\cos(nx)$ for $x\neq k \pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I've found that 
$cos(nx) =-\frac{(sin((n+1)x)-sin(nx)cos(x))}{(sinx))}.$

My question here is how I can show that this succession is convergent  for n approaching $ \to \infty $

Comment: I dont think this is convergent. However it is bounded by 1 and -1. Maybe look into the limes superior and inferior.

Comment: What you've found is incorrect.  Try it for $n=0$.

Comment: Yeah you are right let me edit the question

Comment: You can't, because it's not convergent.

Comment: Since you've only excluded integral multiples of $\pi$, consider e.g. $x = \pi/2$. In this case it should be easy to see that the sequence does not converge.

Comment: What is the relevance of the first identity ? It has no connection to convergence.

Comment: thank you @Marktmeister i proofed that this sequence is not convergent)

Answer (score 2):

If $\cos(nx)$ converges to a limit $c$ , the subsequence $\cos(2nx)$ also converges to $c$. But $\cos(2nx)=2\cos(nx)^2-1$, so $c=2c^2-1$.
In particular, $c\neq 0$.

Now $\cos((n+1)x)+\cos((n-1)x)=2\cos(nx)\cos(x)$.
Taking limits shows that $2c=2c\cos(x)$. Since $c\neq 0$, this implies $\cos(x)=1$, which is not possible since $x\neq k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Contradiction.